# Issue with flock when running script in cron job

Tags: php

I am using the following code:

```
$fp = fopen("lock.txt", "w");
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)) { // do an exclusive lock
    //Do something here.
}else{
   echo "Could not lock file!";
}
```

This code runs fine when I run my script from my browser (it locks and I can only run it once) but when running it via cron job, the lock.txt file isn't even created. I am a little stumped as I presume the Cron runs as the same user that runs the browser version so it obviously has permissions.

Anyone else had something like this?

EDIT: Ok the file is created now I have done specific paths to the directory. However, the file is overwritten everytime the cron starts an isn't actually locking the file.

Comment: Is the current working directory different? You may want to try adding a "chdir" to the top of the script to make sure.

Comment: Why do you presume that it runs as the same user? IME that's a very unusual scenario. Why don't you check?

Comment: chdir() made it work with the file (created it) BUT it didn't lock it .. it just kept overwriting it every 1 minute (when my cron started).

Comment: @symcbean - How would I check? EDIT: Used: echo get_current_user() but no way to run this on my cron as I won't be able to see it.

Comment: Added some debug information in. Its using the same user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to do that.

```
<?php
$tempDir = sys_get_temp_dir() . "/";
$fp = fopen("$tempDirlock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) { // do an exclusive lock
    // do the work

    flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // release the lock
} else {
    echo "Couldn't get the lock!";
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Why r+ ? If the file doesn't exist then it won't create it. Is the W causing my troubles?

Comment: Ok tried your code exactly and it still allows it to run a second time :/

Comment: The file gets locked only for a period of script execution (to be precise until unlocked or file handler is closed `fclose($fp);`, which is also called **automatically** when script finished. How long does your script run? If you start this script every 1 minute and script is finished its job in like 10 seconds ... then file will not be locked when you execute the script next time.

Comment: It loops and loops, its designed not to stop BUT I need to make sure IF it does stop OR is restarted that it starts back up again. I didn't have an issue on my old server. Now it just seems to keep overwriting the file and starting the script again ...

Comment: I see, so no probs here with script execution time. I just tried the code above (but with `c` instead of `r+` (in case you need the file contents) -- `$fp = fopen("{$tempDir}lock.txt", "c");` using sleep() to emulate the loop) .. and it worked fine -- second copy was unable to get the lock. Tested on Windows XP, PHP 5.3.6

Comment: Thats the problem though. I can run this script in mozilla and then try in IE and it shows the lock. However, when my Cron job tries every minute, I get an entry in my log table in the DB saying that it has started it again (i.e ignored / not seen a lock). :(

Comment: Just confirmed that the user the cron runs as is the same as the user the script runs as when running from my broswer .... How odd!!

Comment: Can you try another approach then (if you will unable to sort this out) - instead of locking (which does not work via cron for whatever the reason is) can you base your script logic on the fact that file exist: if file is there then script is running, if not - we are safe to go. Of course you need to ensure that the file will be deleted at the end of script execution. To be more safe - also check the file modification time and if it is bigger than some value (let say 60 secs) then assume that script was forcedly terminated and current copy can be run instead. `touch()` the file in a loop.

Comment: Ok this stops the script running to often but unlink() doesn't seem to work to delete the file ... not my day ...

Comment: Did you the modified-time? May be it is working, since you are running this frequently you might not able to see. Create a unique-file & not a common file name, something like lock-file-123.txt & next time create a different other than this.

Comment: In all fairness, I would prefer to spend my debugging time trying to see why the file won't lock in the first place. There must be something simple I am missing :(

Comment: Try to use XDEBUG and back-trace the flow, you should get something better.

Comment: Just found this comment: `Note: These locks only apply to the current PHP process. Other processes can modify or delete a PHP-locked file if permissions allow.` That means that each cron can ignore the lock if it has permissions to write to the file anyway, yes? SO that would be my problem?

Answer (score 1):

why not use fwrite to overwrite the lock file contents with time() and when your script is finished clear the file.

you can check if the script is running and for how long.